# separate action for [OK] and [IGNORE] button

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

in Oracle Apex I have a page where I want to edit individual records. To do this, the user selects a data record and then clicks the [OK] or [IGNORE] button. Here I have defined that the page is to be sent and then an update and insert takes place under PROCESSING. But he works "logically" one after the other. When I click [OK] an insert and update should take place and when I select [IGNORE] only an update without insert in a table should take place. Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process lets you create a **Server-side condition** which - additionally - offers you to choose which button it is related to.

Therefore, create two processes, each for its own button. Doing so, process will *fire* only when its button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

1. Create one page process per button and put a server side condition on each process (server side condition = When Button Pressed). Same answer as Littlefoot.
2. Create a single page process and in your source you manage the different cases. On submit, the value of the REQUEST is the name of your button. So your page process code could be

```
IF :REQUEST = 'OK' THEN
  --code to execute when OK is pressed
ELSIF :REQUEST = 'IGNORE' THEN
  --code to execute when OK is pressed
END IF;
```

You'd want to put a serverside condition on this of type "Request is contained in value" with a value of "OK;IGNORE". This will yield true if button OK or button IGNORE is pressed.